# How can I find Histogram using arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, methods, data-visualization

Build/Output Histograms using Arrays Where i'm wrong?

This code takes 5 inputs from user in array and show the number of stars for example if user enter 3 then *** would be shown and so on .Where i'm wrong ?

```
  public class P20 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] anArray;
   int Number;
//setup variable value
   anArray = new int [10];
   System.out.println("Enter some numbers between 1 and 100.");

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);

   anArray[0] = 1-9;
   anArray[1] = 10-19;
   anArray[2] = 20-29;
   anArray[3] = 30-39;
   anArray[4] = 40-49;
   anArray[5] = 50-59;
   anArray[6] = 60-69;
   anArray[7] = 70-79;
   anArray[8] = 80-89;
   anArray[9] = 90-100;
   if(anArray > 0) {
  System.out.println("*"+Number );   

  else if(anArray > 20) 
  {
   System.out.println("**"+Number ); 
  }
  else if (anArray > 30) 
  {
   System.out.println("***"+Number ); 
  }    
  else if (anArray > 40) 
  {
   System.out.println("****"+Number ); 
  }            
  else if (anArray > 50) 
  {
  System.out.println("*****"+Number ); } 
 }}
```

Comment: Do you need to add *** when the user inputs 3, or when the user enters 30?

Comment: if 30 then it will print 30 *

Comment: You need to get the input somehow, then do this inside the loop: `anArray[input/10]++;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(anArray > 0) {
```

you always will be `> 0` so you always get only 1 x *

you hve to modify your if clause like that:

```
if (anArray > 0 && anArray < 20){
```

and so on...

edit:-----------------------------------------------------------

like you requested:

```
public String stars(int n) {
    if (n == 1){
      return "*";
    }else{
      return "*" + stars(n-1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you make histogram of star * in java?the user will take input and if user enter 2 then ** would be shown

Answer (score 0):

> This code takes 5 inputs from user in array and show the number of stars for example if user enter 3 then *** would be shown and so on .Where i'm wrong ?

This code doesn't take inputs from the user.

You want the user to input a value and then you print the number of stars he/she wrote. You could do this like that:

```
public class P20 //Why don't you try giving names that are easier to remember
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        for (int i=0; i<args[0]; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
}
```

Where args[0] is the first argument given to the program when called:

```
java P20 3
```

---

Anyway, let me try to point out what some of the mistakes of your code are:

When you wrote:

> anArray[0] = 1-9;

Did you really want to write that wich means "Let the 0th element of the array be the number 1 minus 9" (=-8)?

Or did you intent to input an interval? (Meaning the numbers from 1 to 9).

Then later on you say

> if(anArray > 0)

Which doesn't make sense to me since anArray is an int[] variable and not an int variable. This means that anArray is not a variable which points directly to a number, but one pointing to an array object which holds several int values.